# How were early software and operating systems created?

Tags: software-design

Because nowadays, we are using compilers and interpreters to develop software and operating systems. Example MS Visual Studio, Turbo C++.

Answer (score 0):

Well young fellow, we had to code them up in machine language is what. Not assembler, mind you. Machine language. Raw numbers. And without any a' them fancy macros, neither, no sir. And we had to carry our work to the machine room and then take the results back to our offices. Uphill. Both ways.